# "Ce qui est des" ou "Ce qui sont des"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, usage, conjugaison, pronoms-relatifs

Entre les 2 phrases suivantes :

> Ce qui est des hauteurs des bâtiments.

ou

> Ce qui sont des hauteurs des bâtiments.

Quelle est la bonne et veuillez me préciser la règle svp ?

Ma phrase est celle-ci: "Les mesures de la partie privative ont été prises à partir de la surface visible du revêtement des murs. (**Pour ce qui est / Pour ce qui sont**) des hauteurs entre le plancher et le plafond, elles incluent le revêtement de finition.

C'est vraiment la partie entre parenthèse qui me gène.

Comment: On a besoin du reste de la phrase pour savoir.

Answer (score 1):

Ce groupe de mot forme une unité, une *locution* prépositive servant d'[introducteur](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25159/la-redaction-et-la-communication/organisation-textuelle/liste-de-charnieres) et qui signifie « en ce qui concerne », « quant à », « au sujet de » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour_ce_qui_est_de)) et la tournure est construite avec une proposition relative qui est sans doute figée. *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 1098) classe *pour ce qui est* dans les « introducteurs occasionnels (invariables) » (et on produit entre autres « POUR CE QUI EST DES victimes de l'affaire, l'auteur croit leur avoir fait quelque bien », Balzac). Ce ne sont pas tous les introducteurs qui sont invariables (par exemple le LBU dit de *soit* qu'il est « souvent » invariable.).

Answer (score 1):

***Pour ce qui*** est toujours suivi d'un verbe conjugué à la troisième personne du singulier, sans exception. Il s'agit ici d'une locution prépositive *[Pour ce qui est de](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour_ce_qui_est_de)/du/de la/des*.

*<s>Pour ce qui sont de</s>* est donc impossible.

> **Pour ce qui est des** hauteurs sous plafond, la hauteur du revêtement de sol est incluse.

ou plus simplement :

> La hauteur sous plafond est mesurée revêtement de sol posé.

Pour avoir un verbe au pluriel, il faudrait d'autres tournures mais leur sens est différent :

> *Pour **ceux** qui sont [...]*
> *Pour ce **que** sont [...]*

Comment: merci pour ton explication

Answer (score 0):

À quoi se rapporte le pronom "ce" ?

S'il s'agit d'un nom singulier, j'écrirais :
"ce qui est une hauteur de bâtiment(s)", en faisant varier l'accord de bâtiment à la logique générale de ce dont il s'agit.

S'il s'agit d'un nom au pluriel, j'écrirais :
"qui sont des hauteurs de bâtiment(s)", en giclant le "ce".

Mais il sera de toute manière plus simple de te répondre si tu nous fournis la phrase complète plutôt qu'un tronçon, sans contexte ni sémantique ni syntaxique.

Je trouve de toute façon la forme "X, ce qui est un Y" particulièrement lourde, d'autant qu'elle est en général facilement remplaçable par une alternative plus élégante.

"Pour ce qui est de" => invariable.